# Debian Active Directory to LDAP migration

Tags: linux, active-directory, debian, ldap, migration

These days I am working on LDAP and Active Directory migration. I want to migrate to LDAP but I cannot get passwords from Active Directory. I want to seemlesly migrate to LDAP, and I want a solution like this: I want the client to connect to LDAP and if the user is not yet registered to LDAP, than I want the LDAP server to go to Active Directory and ask for authentication. After Active Directory gives true for authentication, I want LDAP to register it to database in LDAP on its own, and ask for a new password on KDM.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

LDAP Active Directory does not provide LDAP authentication but kerberos authentication instead. If you retrieve AD LDAP (with ldapsearch for instance) users accounts, you will see the Password field left blank, because this is not the place for authentication.

OpenLDAP provide LDAP authentication (which is at some point similar to apache basic auth: cleartext (only encoded) password). Both authentication are not compatible (and LDAP authentication does not provide SSO as kerberos authentication does).

What you should do is create a kerberos server for the authentication. your OpenLDAP database may be retrieve from AD. You will need a cross realm authentication trust between the kerberos getting trusted by the AD (to let users getting authenticated even if they are not yet in the kerberos/OpenLDAP).

You seem anyway to underestimate the difficulties of this task. Completing this is by itself is quite complex. But then, you will have incompatibilities if you need to manage Windows desktops.